# Coldfusion Ajax - Form Submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfform

I Need help with ColdFusion,  I want to use the CF9 ajax library, I've got `<cfajaximport tags="cfform">` in my header, and included a form using `<cfdiv bind="url:domainchecker.cfm">` This however replaces the entire form with the "Loading" ajax wheel then shows the results.

What I need, is for the form to submit, but the a separate results area is what gets updated (and will obviously have the ajax "loading").  I don't want the entire area to to change (does that make sense??)

Answer (score 1):

So, after much soul searching, I managed this:

```
<head>
...
<cfajaximport />
...
    <script>
        function handleResponse(s) {
            if(s == "AVAILABLE") {
                //rewrite span
                var domainspan = document.getElementById('DomainStatus');
                var newcontent = "Available To Register :)";
                domainspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
                var loadingspan = document.getElementById('frmGO');
                var newcontent = "<input name='' value='GO!' class='search_domain_go' type='submit' />";
                loadingspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
            } else {
                //rewrite span
                var domainspan = document.getElementById('DomainStatus');
                var newcontent = "Unavailable To Register :(";
                domainspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
                var loadingspan = document.getElementById('frmGO');
                var newcontent = "<input name='' value='GO!' class='search_domain_go' type='submit' />";
                loadingspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
            }
        }

        function CheckDomain() {
            var loadingspan = document.getElementById('frmGO');
            var newcontent = "<input name='' type='image' class='search_domain_go' src='images/ajax-loader.gif' alt='' />";
            loadingspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
            ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm('frmDomainCheck','checkdomain.cfm',handleResponse);
        }
    </script>
...
</head>

<body>
...
        <div class="search_domain">
            <div class="search_domain_form">
            Search Your Domain Here<br />
                <form method="post" action="" onSubmit="CheckDomain();return false;" id="frmDomainCheck">
                    <input class="search_domain" name="frmURL" id="frmURL" value="Please enter your domain name here..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'Please enter your domain name here...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Please enter your domain name here...';}" type="text" />
                    <span id="frmGO"><input name="" value="GO!" class="search_domain_go" type="submit" /></span>
                <form>
            </div><!-- /# end search form -->
            <div class="domain_features">
                <ul>
                    <li><span id="DomainStatus">Type in the domain and click 'GO' to check its availability.</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use jQuery over CF Ajax functions for something beyond simple binding without too much additional JavaScript.

The [provided JavaScript functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7fff.html) from CF are just too limited.

Since you're already used jQuery, this should be quite easy.  Look at Ajax + Manipulation functions of jQuery.

Comment: Hi Henry, Thanks for the quick reply.  Ive never really used ajax in coldfusion (never needed to) so could you give me an example? Or just point in the direction of a good one.

Of give me an example of what you mean with jQuery (Im using jQuery on the site)

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple?

domainSearch.cfm

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h2 style="color:Blue">Domain search</h2>
<form name="domainSearch">
www.<input class="search_domain" name="searchString" id="frmURL" value="Please enter your domain" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Please enter your domain') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Please enter your domain';}" type="text" />.com
<font color="#FF0000"><strong>[Search]</strong></font>
</form>
<p>Enter any domain.com, (hint: try "free")</p>
<cfdiv id="resultsDiv" bind="url:searchProcessor.cfm?searchString={searchString}">
</body>
</html>
```

searchProcessor.cfm

```
<cfif IsDefined("URL.searchString")>

    <cfif URL.searchString eq "Please enter your domain">
        <cfoutput></cfoutput>   
    <cfelseif URL.searchString eq "free">
        <cfoutput>Great, #URL.searchString# is available, price $400</cfoutput>
    <cfelse>    
        <cfoutput>Sorry, #URL.searchString# is not available, try again.</cfoutput>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```